# Javascript: addEventListener(), removeEventListener() and bind()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add and event listener, I want the function the event listener calls to be bound to the calling scope and I want to be able to remove the listener at some arbitrary date in the future.

The obvious thing doesn't work:

```
function Thing(){
    this.thingINeed = "important!"
}

// the function that does the thing. 
Thing.prototype.handlerFunction = function(e){
    console.log(this.thingINeed)
    e.preventDefault;
}

// do the binding.
window.document.body.addEventListener('click', this.handlerFunction.bind());

// sometime later...this is my best guess. The event listener remains active. 
window.removeEventListener('click', this.handlerFunction.bind());

// this also doesn't work: 
window.removeEventListener('click', this.handlerFunction);
```

So I flogged together some code that *does* work:

```
function Thing(){
    this.thingINeed = "important!"
}

Thing.prototype.handlerFunction = function(e){
    console.log(this.thingINeed);
    e.preventDefault;
}

// Where the 'magic' happens...
this.boundHandlerFunction = this.handlerFunction.bind(this);

window.document.body.addEventListener('click', this.boundHandlerFunction);

// sometime later...
window.removeEventListener('click', this.boundHandlerFunction);
```

[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/removeEventListener#Matching_event_listeners_for_removal) goes into some detail on matching event listeners with removal, but it doesn't mention `.bind()` and I can't find any examples of other people doing it this way. The code isn't exactly obvious without extensive commenting.

Is there a better way?

jQuery event listeners can be named, which makes them really easy to remove, but that isn't possible with vanilla?

Thanks.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend attempting to do it at **all** with jQuery's `.bind()`, considering it was [**deprecated**](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/deprecated-3.0/) in jQuery 3.0. Use `.on()` instead :)

Comment: @ObsidianAge erm. uh, `.bind()` isn't jquery in this question... so... yeah.... no.

Comment: If you used .bind() when adding the event, you have to store the resulting function to be able to unbind it. `foo.bind('bar') !== foo`. there's no way around this.

Comment: The only alternative would be to define an arrow function and store it in a var, then use that to bind the event handler. however... technically that's identical to your current solution, just with a little sugar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue boils down to - `Function.prototype.bind` returns a new function. It works when you set the bound function to a variable and use it in both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` because both are referencing the same function. The first block of code does not work because they are referencing different functions. Here is a contrived example:

```
function foo () {}

// does not work because foo.bind() returns a new function each time
// these functions are not the same object
document.addEventListener('click', foo.bind())
document.removeEventListener('click', foo.bind())

//does work because both reference the same function
var boundFoo = foo.bind()

document.addEventListener('click', boundFoo)
document.removeEventListener('click', boundFoo)
```

I can't speak much to how jQuery handles events under the hood, but there is no getting around this behavior in vanilla JS.

Comment: I figured this was the case. Is there a better way to handle the situation entirely, or would you consider this code acceptable?

Comment: There is no better way to handle this in vanilla JS (added that to the end of my answer). The only change I would make to your code is not storing the bound function as `this.boundHandlerFunction` since there is no benefit to doing so. You can simply do `var boundHandlerFunction = ...` (similar to my example), but that's getting into code style. Both work as you have already figured out :).

Comment: I'm doing `this.boundHandlerFunction` because the listener will be unset in a different `prototype` method, but point taken. Only mentioning to provide context to my question above. Thanks for the help.