# Javascript: Remove bound event handler from outside set up function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to remove an event listener with bound variables from a different function from where the listener was set.

I have already sen [this post that describes how to remove a bound listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46455624/javascript-addeventlistener-removeeventlistener-and-bind) from within the same function, which is different from what I am trying to do:

```
function testBind(var1,var2){
//remove the bound event from within this function <<<
alert('bound event now removed');
}

function setEvent(){
var addEvent =  document.getElementById("testBtn");   
var boundYes = yesFunction.bind( this, this );
addEvent.addEventListener('mouseup', boundYes);
}
```

All of the examples I found have the event listener being removed inside the same function where the event listener is set:

```
addEvent.removeEventListener("mouseup", boundYes );
```

I understand that using bind creates a new event listener every time and to remove the listener you need to set and remove it by the same variable.

How can I properly remove the event listener from the `testBind` function?

Comment: You need to store `boundYes` somewhere where `testBind` can access it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If (due to constraints in your code) [this preferred solution is not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56728744/8526705), another option would be to associate the handler to the element via a custom property:

```
addEvent.boundYes = boundYes; /* Assign boundYes function to element */
```

This would give you the means to access this function handler instance via the DOM element itself when deregistering the `'mouseup'` event during `testBind()`:

```js
function yesFunction() {
  console.log('yesFunction');
}

function testBind(var1, var2) {

  const addEvent = document.getElementById("testBtn");
  const boundYes = addEvent.boundYes;

  /* Check to see if boundYes associated with element */
  if (boundYes) {

    /* Remove the event listener from element */
    addEvent.removeEventListener('mouseup', boundYes);

    /* Disaccoaite the function from element */
    addEvent.boundYes = undefined;
    alert('bound event now removed');
  }
}

function setEvent() {
  var addEvent = document.getElementById("testBtn");
  
  /* Prevent multiple boundYes handlers */
  if (!addEvent.boundYes) {

    var boundYes = yesFunction.bind(this, this);
    addEvent.addEventListener('mouseup', boundYes);

    /* Attach boundYes function to element */
    addEvent.boundYes = boundYes;
  }
}


setEvent();

testBind();
```

```html
<button id="testBtn">testBtn</button>
```

Comment: This is a very creative solution utilizing a technique that is new to me. Thank you very much. Exactly what I needed in my project.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be for `setEvent` to return the bound function, so that `testBind` can remove it:

```js
function testBind(boundListener, element) {
  element.removeEventListener('mouseup', boundListener);
}

function setEvent() {
  var element = document.getElementById("testBtn");
  const yesFunction = () => console.log('listener running');
  var boundListener = yesFunction.bind(this, this);
  element.addEventListener('mouseup', boundListener);
  return { boundListener, element };
}

const { boundListener, element } = setEvent();
testBind(boundListener, element);
```

```html
<button id="testBtn">click</button>
```

You'll need *some* way to pass around the bound function. If you create it in `setEvent`, `setEvent` should return the bound function, or call `testBind` itself, or something like that. You can also create the bound function outside of `setEvent`, pass it to `setEvent`, and also pass it to `testBind`.